# Troubles submitting a jsp form

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a trouble with a JSP form and I can't make it work. Could you explain me why this 
works :

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:form modelAttribute="categoriesItem" method="post"
        action="facebook/categorize">
        <fieldset>
            <form:select path="categories['${liste}']">
                <option value="None" selected>None</option>
                <option value="Family">Family</option>
                <option value="Professionnal">Professionnal</option>
                <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
            </form:select>
            <input type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
```

and this doesn't  ?

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:form modelAttribute="categoriesItem" method="post"
    action="<c:url value="/facebook/categorize" />">
    <fieldset>
        <form:select path="categories['${liste}']">
            <option value="None" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Family">Family</option>
            <option value="Professionnal">Professionnal</option>
            <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
        </form:select>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

As you can see, the only difference is in the  `action` tag and yet, it doesn't work and I get this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/prehandleFacebook.jsp (line: 30, column: 24) Tag &lt;form:form non terminé
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:992)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1274)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Could it be an incompatibility between two EL languages ?

Comment: Which line is line 30?

Comment: `<form:form modelAttribute="categoriesItem" method="post"
    action="<c:url value="/facebook/categorize" />">`

Comment: I'm assuming this jsp is included in another. Can you show some of that?

Comment: There is only pure HTML, i took it away in order to make it more readable.

Comment: I would double check that there aren't any other tags/elements that aren't closed properly or out of order.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
action="facebook/categorize">
```

tells the browser to relativize `facebook/categorize` to the url you are currently on. If you are on `www.myapp.com/myapp/facebook`, when you submit, the browser will POST the request to `www.myapp.com/myapp/facebook/facebook/categorize` (which I assume is wrong). Note that if your path was instead `/facebook/categorize` (extra `/` at start), that would be appended to the host, not the context.

This

```
action="<c:url value="/facebook/categorize" />">
```

gets rendered as a full path (relative to your context root). If your host + context is `myapp.com/myapp`, then it will be rendered as  `myapp.com/myapp/facebook/categorize`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 2nd one (I suppose you cannot include `<c:out...>` into `<form:form...>`).
In this case you will use absolute path.

```
<c:url var="myurl" value="/facebook/categorize" />
<form:form modelAttribute="categoriesItem" method="post"
    action="${myurl}">
```

Comment: That's what I do for now. My question is : is there a reason for this incompatibility ?